# Concatenate value from the same JSON

Tags: json

I'm working on a configuration service in `Angular 2` which simply retrieve the content of my `JSON` file defined above.

```
{
  "application": {
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:1691/",
    "environment": "dev"
  },

  "error": {
    "title": "Title Error",
    "description": "Error message"
  }
}
```

I would like now, to add a properties using the baseUrl and concatenate a string after, I tried with this but it's obviously not working:

```
"baseApiUrl": baseUrl + "api/",
```

Is my requirement possible to do or have I to do it manually in my code?

My dream result would be something like this:

```
{
  "application": {
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:1691/",
    "baseApiUrl": baseUrl + "api/",
    "environment": "dev"
  },

  "error": {
    "title": "Title Error",
    "description": "Error message"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? Also, as you mentioned Angular 2, presumably you're doing this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My dream result would be something like this

JSON has no mechanism for referring to other parts of the structure like that. JSON is a **very** simple data-only format [defined here](http://json.org/).

Assuming you have that JSON as a string, you parse it, then add a property to the `application` object:

```js
var configuration = JSON.parse(configurationString);
configuration.application.baseApiUrl = configuration.application.baseUrl + "api/";
```

Then depending on what you need to do with it, you either use `configuration` (the object), or turn it back into a string via `JSON.stringify`, or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: Well, this is what I was afraid of, I can't do it directly in my json? The main reason was to avoid getting configuration in concatenation for the final user.

Comment: @Sakuto: No. JSON has no mechanism for referring to other parts of the structure.

Comment: That was my only question, I will handle it in another way then. Thanks.